# Does RoomDB supports dropAllTables() and createAllTables()?

Tags: android-room, create-table, greendao, drop-table

GreenDAO supports DaoMaster.dropAllTables() and DaoMaster.createAllTables(). I'm looking for similar functionality in RoomDB. Does RoomDB supports this functionality ??

The use-case for this functionality is, when the user tries to login with new mobile number to my app, i want to clear the data of old login number by showing a warning dialog message and allow login with new number.

Comment: Do you really need to drop and recreate the tables?  Isn't deleting all rows in the tables enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Room supports dropping and creating tables only during a [migration](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions) between schema versions.

You can gain access to the underlying `SupportSQLiteDatabase` via [RoomDatabase.getOpenHelper().getReadableDatabase()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase#getOpenHelper()).  With that, you can use [execSQL()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/sqlite/db/SupportSQLiteDatabase#execSQL(java.lang.String)) to execute SQL statements, include table dropping and creating.

But doing so is not consistent with the intended use of Room and is not safe.  It will very likely break the [InvalidationTracker](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/InvalidationTracker) used to notify observers of changes to managed tables.

From your use-case, it seems like rather than dropping and recreating the tables, all you need to do is clear them by deleting all entries.